# create a div inside a loop and it undifined

Tags: javascript

I don't know why but the chrome developer tool writes=
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined"

Basically the code work fine but it still bothers me

```
function stats() {
  r++;

  if (r / 1 == 2) {
    junkrat = document.getElementById('Junkrat2');
    sigma = document.getElementById('Sigma2');
    sigma.parentNode.removeChild(sigma);
    junkrat.parentNode.removeChild(junkrat);
    document.getElementById("heroesTable2").style.zIndex = 2;
    var t = document.getElementsByClassName("names");
    var s = document.getElementsByClassName("heroes");
    var l = document.getElementsByClassName("heroes2");
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      var div3 = document.createElement("div");
      div3.setAttribute("class", "stats");
      var name = document.createElement("div");
      name.setAttribute("class", "names2");
      var sign = document.createElement("img");
      sign.setAttribute("class", "sign");
      sign.setAttribute("src", "icon/" + t[i].title);
      sign.setAttribute("onclick", "info2()");
      sign.setAttribute("title", t[i].innerText);
      div3.appendChild(sign)[i];
      name.innerText = t[i].innerText;
      l[i].appendChild(div3)[i];
      l[i].appendChild(name)[i];
      l[i].style.left = s[i].offsetLeft;
      l[i].style.top = s[i].offsetTop;
      l[i].style.width = s[i].width;
      l[i].style.height = s[i].height;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide some HTML as well.